# How can I transform moxy json output?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I'm trying to do almost the same thing as [Can I get MOXy to convert a string to a boolean when generating json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451880/can-i-get-moxy-to-convert-a-string-to-a-boolean-when-generating-json).

I go from xml -> object. Objects now contains geometries that I want to output as GeoJson.

I tried to add xml-java-type-adapters in my xml-bindings.xml, but they never seem to run. Annoations in package-info.java runs, but affects xml-> object too, instead of just object->json. Thats why I thought the xml mapping override was a good idea.

Right now I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings package-name="se.lantmateriet.geoaccess.outrettfastighetsomrade.jaxb" xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
<java-types>
    <java-type name="OutrettFastighetsomradeReferensType">
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-element java-attribute="centralpunkt">
                <xml-java-type-adapter value="se.lantmateriet.sercxi.web.controller.GeoJsonAdapter"/>
            </xml-element>
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>
</java-types>
```

and some demo code:

```
    List<OutrettFastighetsomradeReferensType> result = this.outrettFastighetsomradeReferensRepository
        .getByExternIdStartsWith(decodeUtf8String(externId));

    List<InputStream> metadata = Lists.newArrayList(new ClassPathResource("json-bindings.xml").getInputStream());

    Map<String, List<InputStream>> properties = ImmutableMap.of(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, metadata);

    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setLazyInit(true);
    jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPaths("se.lantmateriet.sercxi.gateway.outrettfastighetsomrade.config", "se.lantmateriet.geoaccess.jaxb.gml",
        "se.lantmateriet.geoaccess.outrettfastighetsomrade.jaxb");
    jaxb2Marshaller.setJaxbContextProperties(properties);

    jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

    StringResult stringResult = new StringResult();

    Marshaller marshaller = jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext().createMarshaller();

    marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    marshaller.marshal(result.get(0), stringResult);

    return stringResult.toString();
```

XMLAdapter:

```
public class GeoJsonAdapter extends XmlAdapter<PointPropertyType, Map<String, Object>> {

@Override
public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(final PointPropertyType v) throws Exception {
    return JTSGeometryToGeoJsonConverter.convertGeometryToJson(POSITION(N(v.getPoint().getPos().getValue().get(0)),
        E(v.getPoint().getPos().getValue().get(1))).toPoint());
}

@Override
public PointPropertyType marshal(final Map<String, Object> v) throws Exception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

}

And domain object that I whos property centralpunkt I want to convert in the json output (I have this code in a third party jar, cannot change it):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OutrettFastighetsomradeReferensType", namespace = "http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/outrettfastighetsomrade/v1", propOrder = {
"objektidentitet",
"fodelsenummer",
"externId",
"fastighetsomradetyp",
"centralpunkt"
})
public class OutrettFastighetsomradeReferensType {

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/outrettfastighetsomrade/v1", required = true)
protected String objektidentitet;
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/outrettfastighetsomrade/v1", required = true)
protected String fodelsenummer;
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/outrettfastighetsomrade/v1", required = true)
protected String externId;
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/outrettfastighetsomrade/v1", required = true)
protected FastighetsomradeTypType fastighetsomradetyp;
@XmlElement(name = "Centralpunkt", namespace = "http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/outrettfastighetsomrade/v1", required = true)
protected PointPropertyType centralpunkt;
```

But it's not working :-(

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NullPointerException]
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:915)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:848)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:182)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:129)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:137)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:108)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:258)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:412)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromContextPath(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:470)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:443)
... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.updateGlobalElements(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3868)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:735)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildNewTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:4746)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processReferencedClass(AnnotationsProcessor.java:838)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:812)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:734)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.XMLProcessor.processXML(XMLProcessor.java:364)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:104)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:912)
... 85 more
```

Any ideas?

This is what I really want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
<xml-java-type-adapters>
    <xml-java-type-adapter value="se.lantmateriet.sercxi.web.controller.GeoJsonAdapter" type="se.lantmateriet.geoaccess.jaxb.gml.PointPropertyType"/>
</xml-java-type-adapters>
```

But that doesnt seem to affect anything. xml-java-type-adapter at a global level seems kind of undocumented?

Thanks,

/Magnus

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in play.  Below is my first try at the answer:

---

### Creating the `XmlAdapter`

Since you are trying to adapt the `PointPropertyType` class you have your `XmlAdapter` backwards.  Instead of this.

```
public class GeoJsonAdapter extends XmlAdapter<PointPropertyType, Map<String, Object>> {
```

You should have:

```
public class GeoJsonAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Map<String, Object>, PointPropertyType> {
```

---

### Map as the Value Type of the `XmlAdapter`

Currently there is an issue using a `Map` as the value type in the `XmlAdapter` (see below).  For now you should use a regular POJO instead.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/421680

---

### Specifying Package Level Adapters

**MOXy Metadata (json-bindings.xml)**

When you specify an `XmlAdapter` at the package level via JAXB annotations or MOXy's metadata document it will apply to all mapped field/properites belonging to classes in that package.  In the sample document below, the `se.lantmateriet.sercxi.web.controller.GeoJsonAdapter` XmlAdapter will be applied to a fields/properties of type `se.lantmateriet.geoaccess.jaxb.gml.PointPropertyType` that belong to classes in the `forum19952922` package.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_4.xsd" 
    version="2.4"
    package-name="forum19952922">
        <xml-java-type-adapters>
            <xml-java-type-adapter value="se.lantmateriet.sercxi.web.controller.GeoJsonAdapter" type="se.lantmateriet.geoaccess.jaxb.gml.PointPropertyType" />
        </xml-java-type-adapters>
</xml-bindings>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html

---

### Simplifying the Bootstrap

Below is a code sample that will help simplify your bootstrap process.  If the location given as a `String` matches a relative file location that file will  be loaded, if not the location will be tried as a resource on the class path.

```
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum19952922/json-bindings.xml");
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Root.class}, properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks! I'm almost there! :)

I seem to have the same (?) problem as [MOXy marshal List<?> how to avoid that it shows the type in json results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966861/moxy-marshal-list-how-to-avoid-that-it-shows-the-type-in-json-results).

My adapter is now (is this what you meant by using a pojo?):

```
public class GeoJsonPointAdapter extends XmlAdapter<PointWrapper, PointPropertyType> {

    public static class PointWrapper {

        public String type;

        public Double[] coordinates;

        PointWrapper() {
            super();
        }

        public PointWrapper(final Map<String, Object> data) {
            super();
            this.type = (String) data.get("type");
            this.coordinates = (Double[]) data.get("coordinates");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public PointWrapper marshal(final PointPropertyType v) throws Exception {
        return new PointWrapper(JTSGeometryToGeoJsonConverter.convertGeometryToJson(POSITION(N(v.getPoint().getPos().getValue().get(0)),
        E(v.getPoint().getPos().getValue().get(1))).toPoint()));
    }

    @Override
    public PointPropertyType unmarshal(final PointWrapper v) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Test code:

```
List<Object> result = Lists.newArrayList();

    result.addAll(this.outrettFastighetsomradeReferensRepository.getByExternIdStartsWith(decodeUtf8String(externId)));

    Map<String, Object> properties = Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(2);
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "json-bindings.xml");
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { OutrettFastighetsomradeReferensType.class }, properties);

    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

    StringResult stringResult = new StringResult();

    marshaller.marshal(result, stringResult);

    return stringResult.toString();
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor for class java.util.ArrayList was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.descriptorNotFoundInProject(XMLMarshalException.java:140)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context$ContextState.getSession(Context.java:143)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:787)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:1)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context.getSession(Context.java:451)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.getSession(XMLContext.java:356)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:142)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:487)
... 73 more
```

If I change to marshal one item from the list:

```
marshaller.marshal(result.get(0), stringResult);
```

it all works. Whats the problem?